# Adwords API report segmenting

Tags: google-ads-api

i'm trying to create google adwords report that will gain me

clicks,shows,cost,bounce,goal reach count

for each:
ad id, pharse id, goal id, day
(like group by)

There are a lot of different report types and i can't get how to create that kind of report.

Im using googleads-php-lib, so here is the code from example:

```
    $selector = new Selector();
    $selector->fields = array('Id', 'Clicks', 'Cost');
    // Optional: use predicate to filter out paused criteria.
    //$selector->predicates[] = new Predicate('Status', 'NOT_IN', array('PAUSED'));
    // Create report definition.
    $reportDefinition = new ReportDefinition();
    $reportDefinition->selector = $selector;
    $reportDefinition->reportName = 'Criteria performance report #' . uniqid();
    $reportDefinition->dateRangeType = 'LAST_90_DAYS';
    $reportDefinition->reportType = 'AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT';
    $reportDefinition->downloadFormat = 'CSV';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you can't get all data in the same report. You can see all the report types in the AdWords Docs:

https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports

Comment: Yep, it's impossible to get keywords and placement in the same report. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can add Segment in selector->fields

Example: **ClickType** is a segment so it will be implemented as given below.

```
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'Clicks', 'Cost', 'ClickType');
```

or with CriteriaReportWithAwql

```
$query = (new ReportQueryBuilder())
        ->select([
            'CampaignId',
            'CampaignName',
            'Impressions',
            'Clicks',
            'Cost',
            'ClickType',
            'AccountCurrencyCode',
        ])
        ->from(ReportDefinitionReportType::CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT)
        ->where('Status')->in(['ENABLED', 'PAUSED'])
        ->where('CampaignId')->in(['90045151'])
        ->during($startDate, $endDate)
        ->build();
```